# ¿Cómo agregar scroll dinámico a un dataTable después de creado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, datatables

Tengo una tabla la cual la adapto a `DataTable`, en esto tengo dos problemas con los `scroll` debido a que la tabla de por sí tiene un tamaño, entonces, si tiene pocos datos no necesita un `scrollY`, al momento de definir el `DataTable` defino de una vez el `scrollY`, pero sí son pocos datos, no hace el `scroll`, esto me daña un poco el diseño, no es muy notable, pero está. Lo mismo ocurre en el ancho, solo que aquí sí es mucho más notable, dada la situación, lo que quiero es que si la tabla es menor a cierto ancho o mayor, ponga el `scrollX` y lo mismo con el `scrollY`, sí hay una forma, por favor, háganmela saber.

Dejo el código donde llamo el `DataTable` con `JQuery`

```
function tableDT(){
        tableData = $('#table').DataTable( {
            //scrollY: "400px",
            //scrollX: "740px",
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false,
            columnDefs:[{
                targets: "_all",
                sortable: false
            }],
            rowReorder: {
                selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
            },
            responsive: true
        });
    }
```

Así se ve sí activo las propiedades `scrollX` y `scrollY`
[image: tabla muestra]

Demo en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52cnsdge/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo las referencias del sitio oficial donde explican como definir un scrollX y scrollY: [Scrolling DataTable](https://datatables.net/extensions/autofill/examples/initialisation/scrolling.html) y [Scroll - vertical, dynamic height](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_dynamic.html)
.

Básicamente lo que debes hacer es definir un alto o ancho mínimo para iniciar el scroll, en la segunda referencia se puede ver que se hace uso CSS3 para dar el ancho a partir de `vh` que sería el alto del `viewport` actual (espacio visible).

Tu código quedaría así, solo con scroll vertical, el horizontal lo debe poner la propiedad responsive:

```
function tableDT(){
        tableData = $('#table').DataTable( {
            scrollY: "50vh",
            //scrollX: "740px",
            //scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false,
            columnDefs:[{
                targets: "_all",
                sortable: false
            }],
            rowReorder: {
                selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
            },
            responsive: true
        });
    }
```

Comment: Voy a probar, pero te comento que el horizontal no lo pone

Comment: Bueno, ahora sí lo pone, pero se ve mal, no hay forma de que se agregue después?

Comment: También puedes habilitar el scrollX con `vh`, haz la prueba con `50vh` también.

Comment: Es que lo que digo en la pregunta, se daña el diseño, se desacomodan las columnas y eso, entonces por eso lo pensé en agregarle esa propieda ya después de creado

Comment: No sé sí sea posible

Comment: Puedes agregarlo un `style="width:100%"` desde la etiqueta table en el HTML, para que siempre ocupe el 100%.

Comment: Ya está de esa manera, ahí te muestro como se ve cuando activo ambas propiedades del scroll

Comment: Es muy extraño ¿Es posible que crees un snippet en la pregunta, Codepen o JSFiddle? Para poder ir probando.

Comment: El problema es que los datos se llenan desde la base de datos, pero ya miro con datos improvisados

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregue a la pregunta

Comment: Veo que en el fiddle no se daña el diseño. ¿Qué problema te presenta ahí? ¿O como puedo replicarlo?

Comment: Pon el editor layout en Tabs (rows) y no lo ajustes, y veras que las columnas quedan corridas, la cuestión es esa, como la vista el pequeña, entonces se acomoda bien, no es como en una pagina completa

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que se me ocurre es que si tu dataTable tiene que cargar 4 registros y tu le permites mostrar los 4 registros, entonces no necesita hacer ningun tipo de scroll. De forma que yo lo primero que probaria es a limitar el numero de registros que puede mostrar en cada pagina. Creo que dataTable tiene muchas versiones desde que emprecé a utilizarlo. En los dataTables que yo tengo creados utilizo...

```
"iDisplayLength": 3,
```

(Pero es posible que este obsoleto en versiones posteriores.)

Tambien limitaria la altura del dataTable.

```
"bAutoHeight": false,
```

Y le indicaria cual es la altura del área de scroll

```
"scrollY": "460px",
"scrollCollapse": true,
```

Prueba a ver si esto te solventa el problema.